# Insert scrollbar in OpenLayers ol-ext popup?

Tags: openlayers, popup, ol-ext

I am using PopupFeature popup http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js as per the example in http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/popup/ map.popup.feature.html.

Does anyone know if it's possible to include a scrollbar according to the amount of attributes?

```
var popup = new ol.Overlay.PopupFeature({
popupClass: 'default anim',
select: select,
canFix: true,
template: function(f) {
  return {
    title: function(f) { return f.get('nom')+' ('+f.get('id')+')' },
    attributes: { 
      region: { title: 'Région' }, 
      arrond: 'arrond', 
      cantons: 'cantons', 
      communes: 'communes', 
      pop: 'pop' 
    }
  }
},
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `overflow` and `max-height` and/or `max-width` CSS properties for `ol-popup-content` CSS class.

For example, if you set:

```css
.ol-popup {
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 1em;
}
.ol-popup-content {
  overflow: auto !important;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

you will get:

[image]

Comment: Very good, thank you. That's right I need.